# JQueryUI Theme Roller - Is it still supported in 2020?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, themeroller

Sorry if there is already a similar question but I couldn't find any. I often use JQuery UI's theme roller for my work. This year it's been pretty difficult to deal with it. First, in the summer, it was impossible to download the theme after editing it and changing the colors as it led me straight to a 521 server error. I found an alternative website in one of the jquery forums - https://jqueryui.templersmc.net/ - but it no longer functions either.

I recently decided to try again but now any sort of customization on the page is impossible. The different options simply don't open and after examining the code in Inspect Element I saw they are just empty links leading to the same page so there is no option to create a new theme or edit an old one. I'm attaching a screenshot.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Do you have any idea if the theme roller is still being supported or should I start looking for alternatives? Any recommendations?

Thank you in advance, I'd appreciate any answers as I can't anything on Jquery's official site.

Comment: At the bottom, you will see: *If you're having trouble downloading a custom package or theme, please report the issue on GitHub.* With a Link: https://github.com/jquery/download.jqueryui.com/issues

Comment: Looking at the latest issue, "Theme Roller Not Working #566", there was an update 8 days ago. So I would check there to see the status.

Answer (score 0):

Try the suggested work around: https://download.jqueryui.com/themeroller/

> Until that's fixed, you can use https://download.jqueryui.com/themeroller/.